# Date conversion in MSSQL query not working when displayed via PHP

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, pdo

I have a PDO statement, thus. The data is coming from a SQL Server database:

```
//Get full record from form108 database
$data = $con->prepare("SELECT CONVERT(varchar, p.WorkBeginDate, 101), * FROM Employee AS e 
INNER JOIN EmployeeProjectInfo AS p ON e.empUIN = p.empUIN WHERE e.empUIN = :empuin AND   
p.UID = :uid");
$input = array('empuin'=>$_SESSION['UIN'],'uid'=>$_SESSION['ID']);
$data->execute($input);
```

Everything displays fine except the date. Instead of the desired format, mm/dd/yyyy, I get yyyy-mm-dd. My hope was that the CONVERT() function would work like the DATE_FORMAT() function in MySQL. The data type in the database is date. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: date is stored as yyyy-mm-dd. Why do you assume that the application or the database know that your desired format is mm/dd/yyyy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theres nothing wrong... all you have to do is change it to the previous format. Here's a very basic example:

```
$mydate = $result['dateField'];
echo date('m/d/Y', strtotime($mydate)); //prints: 12/25/2013
```

Comment: Thanks, that did work. Is there no way to do it within the query? In MySQL, I've used the DATE_FORMAT function with success. I guess it doesn't work the same way in MSSQL?

Comment: I dont know much about mssql but ive found something useful: http://mysqltomssql.blogspot.com.br/2011/04/dateformat-syntax.html and http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx ... hope it help.